# how to use divide() method in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

Im using  iReport1.3.3 tool to create pdf and xls  template ..
     My problem is for the below expression,

```
     ($V{strloanNo}).divide($V{loanCalculation})
```

i need to divide both the variables but i am not getting expected result. it is displaying "null" value .

any idea guys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$V{x}.divide( $V{y} )
```

This works for me.

It looks like your variables are Null.

Make sure to set the Initial Value Expression in the variable's properties.

I set both of mine to below.

```
new java.math.BigDecimal(10.0)
```

Comment: i did not know about `.divide()` +1 what about multiplication ?!

Answer (score 2):

Guess you can try this out -

```
$V{strloanNo}.floatValue()/$V{loanCalculation}.floatValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was discussed 
[here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/515055/math-bigdecimal-variables), you can check this:

`$F{Attribute_a}.divide($F{Attribute_b}, new MathContext(100`))

If your division results in a non-terminating decimal then an exception is thrown. So you scale simply it to something reasonable and exception be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$F{Attribute_a}.divide($F{Attribute_b})
```

and class type should be `java.math.BigDecimal`

if attribute `b` is zero, please put the condition