# How to calculate division and multiply in Jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have problem when I try to calculate an expression in Jasper.
The error message show after I run the report.

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : new Integer(($F{total_answer}.intValue()) / ($F{total_max_score}.intValue()*100)) 
Can't find the translation for key = time_picker: using default (Time)  Can't find the translation for key = time_picker: using default (Time)  For input string: ""  For input string: ""  java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

This my code:

```
new Integer(($F{total_answer}.intValue()) / ($F{total_max_score}.intValue()*100))
```

Anyone know about this?

Comment: Did you check the `$F{total_max_score}` for 0 and null value?

Comment: Seems like some expression that you are using is being divided by zero. Are you using only this one?

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution

[how to use divide() method in jasper reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718943/how-to-use-divide-method-in-jasper-reports)

And note to check for nullity by assigning the initial value to 0.

`${total_answer}.divide( ${total_max_score} )`

and you can do the same for multiplication using `.multiply()`